# Find all files that use `print` but do not have `from __future__ import print_function`

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I'm migrating a codebase from 2.7 to 3.6, and would like to ensure that all files that use `print` do the `__future__` import.

How do I `find/grep/ack` recursively through a multi-package codebase to find all files that use `print` but don't have the `from __future__ import print_function`?

I know that `2to3` should handle this automatically, but I've seen one instance where there is a print expression of the form `print("updated database: ", db_name)` in a file that does *not* include print-function import.  Running `2to3-2.7` on this file transforms the line to `print(("updated database: ", db_name))`, which changes the output.  I would like to find all instances where this problem might arise in order to fix them before running the automated tool

Comment: That shouldn't change the output at all... The extra parens would just perform a no-op grouping output.

Comment: How about using IDE, if you set the inspection to 2.7, it will throw errors if you don't have that `future`.

Comment: @ShadowRanger found the actually problematic one in terms of output.

Comment: @Barmar `2to3` automagically fixes print statements.  My search problem is that some, say 1/2, of the files do include the future import (so just searching for `print(` won't work), and the other half don't do the future import, and a handfull of those have `print(...)` w/o the future import.

Comment: "which changes the output" How so? With old style print the single parentheses output a tuple, with new style print the double parentheses output a tuple as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind doing this in Python itself:

```
import os

for folder, subfolder, files in os.walk('/my/project/dir'): 
    scripts = [f for f in files if f.endswith('.py')] 
    for script in scripts: 
        path = os.path.join(folder, script) 
        with open(path, 'r') as file: 
            text = file.read() 
        if "print" in text and "print_function" not in text: 
            print("future print import not found in file", path)
```

Answer (score 0):

2 egreps (works with Mac egrep and gnu egrep, others dunno) --

```
#!/bin/bash

fileswithprint=` egrep --files-with-matches --include '*.py' --recursive  -w print  $* `
    # -R: Follow all symbolic links, unlike -r
    # too long: see xargs

egrep --files-without-match '^from __future .*print_function'  $fileswithprint
```